# My BizTalk functoid returns true value regardless of the boolean being passed

Tags: c#, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I am having an issue on my BizTalk application

I have customized the functoid to change value based on the boolean it has received her is the code

```
 public string GetBoolMark(bool param1)
        {
            string returnValue = "0";
            if (param1 == true )
            {
                returnValue = "1";
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
```

I am having an issue that the value always returns the true value. I am using BizTalk server 2013 R2

Comment: Yes, a known issue with BizTalk 2013 and up, do what Gary suggested and treat them as strings

Comment: Hold on, as I mentioned in your other thread, we need to know the Type of the source node.  Yes, it can make a difference.

Comment: See Known issues in BizTalk Server 2013 https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2954101 Known Issues in XSLCompiledTransform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of param1 from bool to string.
Parse it carefully inside you function to a boolean, and use that boolean to decide what to return.

```
 public string GetBoolMark(string param1)
    {
        bool condition;
        string returnValue = "0";

        if (bool.TryParse(param1, out condition) && condition)
        {
            returnValue = "1";
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

When using the inline C# in a scripting functoid, I always find it easier to assume all parameters are strings.
If you use other type, some implicit parsing will be performed for you. I'd rather perform the parsing myself explicitly because I don't know exactly how the implicit parsing works.

Comment: Thanks Gary will update the code in my functoid and test

Comment: Thanks Gary i have updated my code as to what you have provided and it works thanks for the assistance

Comment: @isir Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept this answer in stackoverflow, if it did help you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is indeed xs:boolean, you can do:

```
public MyFunctoid(string MyParam)
{
     if(MyParam == "true")
     {
          return "It was true!";
     }
     return "It was false!";
}
```

This is because the value of MyParam can be one of only 3 things, 'true', 'false' or ''.  You only need to test for 'true'.  This is one case where a [Try]Parse is not necessary.